# DUKPT MAC Variant key

Tags: mac, key-derivation

I'm currently implementing an interface that makes use of the **DUKPT** (Derived Unique Key Per Transaction) scheme to generate **MAC keys**. This particular interface uses a different (**variant**) of the **MAC key** on the response than used on the request.

This particular variant key seems to course some trouble in our HSM (it's don't work .. ), and I'm wondering if it is standard to have two keys in use on **DUKPT MAC**. Many references seems to only talk about one MAC key when talking about **DUKPT**.

Comment: DUKPT seems to refer to a specific algorithm used for banks (of old?). Is there any specification that you can point out? Note that having a separate MAC key for receiving and sending definitely **is** good practice - you don't want to have your own messages played back to you by an adversary. If this is also the case for your particular protocol remains to be seen.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: Yes DUKPT was designed for banks (ATMs in fact) a good while ago but it's still used for many payment processing systems; the spec is X9.24 from x9.org but is not free. We have several Qs on it already; https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/27533/triple-des-dukpt-cbc-pin-variant-vs-data-variant and especially https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37281574/decrypt-3des-dukpt-per-the-ansi-x9-24-part-1-standard look closest.